# Why does instanceof on Java give a compilation error?

Tags: java

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

```
A x = new B();
B y = new B();
```

```
x instanceof C
y instanceof C
```

Why does `y instanceof C` give a compilation error (incompatible types) when `x instanceof C` works fine?

Comment: what do you mean, an error? it should just return false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the compiler can tell that `y instanceof C` can never return `true`, it produces a compilation error. The compile time type of `y` is `B`, and class `B` has no relation to class `C`. Therefore, an instance of class `B` can never be an instance of class `C`.

On the other hand, `x instanceof C` may return `true`, since the compile time type of `x` is `A`, and `C` is a sub-clsss of `A`.

JLS refrence:

> [15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)
>
> If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true.

Comment: Worth noting that if `C` was an interface, the compiler would let that instanceof through even if B didn't implement it.

Comment: @ernest_k that's true, since even if `B` doesn't implement `C`, a sub-class of `B` might implement it.